# Not able to parse a json file, says No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: python, json

I have a json dump as

```
{
  "alarm": [
    {
      "ackId": 16,
      "count": 1,
      "description": "<p>A SSH outage was identified on interface\n      10.21.5.39.</p> <p>A new Outage record has been\n      created and service level availability calculations will be\n      impacted until this outage is resolved.</p>",
      "firstEventTime": 1495277308427,
      "id": 16,
      "ifIndex": null,
      "ipAddress": "10.21.5.39",
      "lastEvent": {
        "createTime": 1495277308437,
        "description": "<p>A SSH outage was identified on interface\n      10.21.5.39.</p> <p>A new Outage record has been\n      created and service level availability calculations will be\n      impacted until this outage is resolved.</p>",
        "display": "Y",
        "host": "opennms",
        "id": 625,
        "ifIndex": null,
        "ipAddress": "10.21.5.39",
        "log": "Y",
        "logMessage": "SSH outage identified on interface 10.21.5.39 with reason code: Connection refused (Connection refused).",
        "nodeId": 9,
        "nodeLabel": "fra01-api-01",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "eventReason",
            "type": "string",
            "value": "Connection refused (Connection refused)"
          }
        ],
        "serviceType": {
          "id": 5,
          "name": "SSH"
        },
        "severity": "MINOR",
        "source": "OpenNMS.Poller.DefaultPollContext",
        "time": 1495277308427,
        "uei": "uei.opennms.org/nodes/nodeLostService"
      },
      "lastEventTime": 1495277308427,
      "logMessage": "SSH outage identified on interface 10.21.5.39 with reason code: Connection refused (Connection refused).",
      "managedObjectInstance": null,
      "managedObjectType": null,
      "nodeId": 9,
      "nodeLabel": "fra01-api-01",
      "ossPrimaryKey": null,
      "parameters": [
        {
          "name": "eventReason",
          "type": "string",
          "value": "Connection refused (Connection refused)"
        }
      ],
      "qosAlarmState": null,
      "reductionKey": "uei.opennms.org/nodes/nodeLostService::9:10.21.5.39:SSH",
      "serviceType": {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "SSH"
      },
      "severity": "MINOR",
      "suppressedTime": 1495277308427,
      "suppressedUntil": 1495277308427,
      "type": 1,
      "uei": "uei.opennms.org/nodes/nodeLostService",
      "x733AlarmType": null,
      "x733ProbableCause": 0
    }
  ],
  "count": 1,
  "offset": null,
  "totalCount": 1
}
```

I wrote a small code to get some details from the json

```
def get_nodes_opennms():
    headers={'Accept': 'application/json' }
    x = requests.get('http://localhost:8980/opennms/rest/alarms?comparator=ge&severity=MINOR?limit=0',headers=headers , auth=('admin', 'Op3AD'))
    parsed = json.loads(x.content)
    #print json.dumps(parsed, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
    wriet_me_to_file = json.dumps(parsed, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
    f=open('out.txt', 'w')
    f.write(wriet_me_to_file)
    for i in json.load(open('out.txt'))["alarm"]:
        try:
            print (["ipAddress"])
            print (["logMessage"])
        except Exception as e:
          print "something is wrong"
```

This is throwing me error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "python_opennms.py", line
>   24, in 
>       x = get_nodes_opennms()   File "python_opennms.py", line 15, in get_nodes_opennms
>       for i in json.load(open('out.txt'))["alarm"]:    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/**init**.py", line 291, in load
>       **kw)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/**init**.py", line 339, in loads
>       return _default_decoder.decode(s)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
>       obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
>       raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded") ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Can someone help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening file that is not closed after writing. Probably system did not flush stream buffer to disk completly, so `open('out.txt')` encountered file with not complete content.

Best and most secure approach would be:

```
with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(wriet_me_to_file)
for i in json.load(open('out.txt'))["alarm"]:
```

Comment: okay cool , got it,, but it just returns me `['ipAddress']
['logMessage']
`

Comment: because you wrote: `print (["ipAddress"])`
insetad of print( **i** ["ipAddress"])
That's why variable name `i` is not good for something else than just list index :)